# Can't import Datastore from google.cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create a basic web app using Flask and Google Datastore to make myself to Google Cloud. Though, when I deploy my app, I get an Error 500, the details being that Python can't import Datastore : `ImportError: No module named cloud`.

Here is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
- name: flask
  version: 0.12
```

My `main.py` starts like follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# Standard imports
import time
import logging
import json
import threading

# Flask framework
from flask import request
from flask import Flask

# Google Cloud features
from google.cloud import datastore
# the following replaces requests
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
```

Finally, my `requirements.txt` is the following:

```
Flask
google-cloud
click
```

When I deploy my app (using `gcloud app deploy`) and get to my site, I get my error 500.

I don't understand why I can't use `from google.cloud import datastore` since it's what Google does in their tutorial... I must be missing something but I can't find what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

From [Installing the client library](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library):

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-datastore
```

The client library you need (to match your import statement) is `google-cloud-datastore`, but you don't have that listed in your `requirements.txt` file.

Side note: your `app.yaml` file indicates your app is a standard env GAE app one, for which you have the optimized [Google Datastore NDB Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) library available, already included in your SDK (if you don't have specific reasons for choosing the generic one instead).

Comment: There's something I don't really understand and you might clear up. Are the `requirements.txt` used when I deploy the app or not? From my understanding, only the modules available in `/lib` mattered... But it's something I'm far from sure about. Also, I added an `appengine_config.py` file that adds the files in `lib` and now Datastore works correctly, but I'd really want to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: The `requirements.txt` file is NOT used during deployment for standard env apps - for those deployment only looks at the app directory (and at the `skip_files` config, if any). But such file *can* be used in the standard env during vendoring in 3rd party libs - by passing the file as argument to a single `pip` invocation for installing all its content in an app dir, usually called `lib` - but using it is NOT mandatory (manual `pip` invocations can be used instead just as well). I only mentioned it because you did. Such file is however used in the GAE flex environment (different beast).

Comment: So you mean that if I want to use Datastore, I have to install it using pip to my `lib` folder, right? Also, can you confirm me that after installing modules to `/lib`, I **have** to use an `appengine_config.py` file to configure vendoring?

Comment: If you want to use *that* datastore client library.  You can still use the Datastore, but with the ndb client library - the recommended way, for which you don't need to vendor anything else - it's already in the SDK. The rest is correct, the whole vendoring procedure is here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library

Comment: In case it's not clear, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/ and the other related section under Google Cloud Datastore in the left-side navigation column of the GAE-specific docs.

Answer (score 4):

You do not specify `env: flex` so you are using Standard Environment. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#env) it is described for flex yaml and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) it doesn’t appear for standard yaml.

This is important because google-cloud is not supported for Standard Environment. [google-cloud’s repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python):

> These libraries currently do not run on Google App Engine Standard

Link mentioned by Dan Cornilescu about the [NDB Client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) is an oficial solution for standard environment and few examples can be found in the oficial documentation:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/ndb and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/multitenancy

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that explains much. But when am I supposed to do to use it, then?

Comment: Link mentioned by Dan Cornilescu about the [NDB Client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) is an oficial solution for standard environment and you can also see an example in oficial documentation:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/ndb and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/multitenancy

I updated my answer.