# Cannot import Google Cloud Datastore library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing a App Engine Standard python application, which accesses Datastore.

However importing google-cloud-datastore library triggers this error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/qiuchen/PycharmProjects/recsys_v1/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.cloud import datastore
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1147, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.cloud.datastore
```

There are the beginning of my codes:

```
    import webapp2

    from google.appengine.ext import ndb

    from google.cloud import datastore
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't import Datastore from google.cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378833/cant-import-datastore-from-google-cloud)

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't normally need the datastore library in a standard env python app - `ndb` is a better choice and it's already included.

Comment: thx, I have used ndb to get the data. It is great tool!

Answer (score 1):

As the [google-cloud-python GitHub page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) says, google-cloud-python client libraries are not currently supported for App Engine Standard.

The recommended approach is to use the [ndb client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) to access Datastore. ndb is specifically designed for App Engine Standard.